# Create Hash from Integer using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, hash, md5, md5sum

I am trying to create a Hash from an integer using SQL. The purpose of this is to create a function in which I will know if the data received has not been tampered with by the person running the script. I figured I would MD5-hash the integer however I am running into some issues with the MD5 hash not being accurate.

Here is my test code where I try to convert `20` into the MD5

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(32),HashBytes('MD5', STR(20)),2) as 'MD5'
```

returns `F63258CAB6D44ED830605298043CBEA4` and

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(32),HashBytes('MD5', '20'),2) as 'MD5'
```

returns the expected result of `98F13708210194C475687BE6106A3B84`

What am I doing wrong with my conversion?

Also I do not have to use MD5. I am open to suggestions of using a different method in which it would be easy for me to decrypt but hard for the average user to reverse-engineer even if they saw the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you check the result of `STR(20)` you will notice some leading spaces.

Try `LTRIM(20)` or `cast(20 as varchar(12))` instead.